# How to identify dead ends in road network using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, density, connectivity-analysis

How to identify dead ends in road network using QGIS? And then how to calculate Street dead ends Density with QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "mark".

Comment: select points with only one line meeting them

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @IanTurton I am doing analysis on calculating intersections and dead ends of a street network. I can calculate the density of intersections but facing difficulty in calculating dead ends of a street.

Comment: [This thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/427789/128665) has multiple ways to calculate the dead ends (or dangles) of a network.

Comment: @Matt Thank you so much!