# Cleaning parallel lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, generalization, parallel-lines

I'm using QGIS 3.22.0. I downloaded the OSM Railway Line-Shape, however, some lines are parallel. I would like to "clean" the layer and only have one line per achse displayed (and in railway station have one line instead of all the tracks).

I went through all the relevant questions posted here such as ([Simplifying multiple lines to create central axis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319412/simplifying-multiple-lines-to-create-central-axis)), but its not working. Is there any other solution?

This is how my Layer looks after I exploded the lines and extracted the vertices [image]

Comment: So what exactly does not work with the solutions in the linked post? If I understood you correctly, you want the result that can be seen in the screenshots of the accepted answer, right? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/418644/88814

Comment: Correct! first of all I tried the HCMGIS-Plugin. Installing it was no problem, but using the function create skeleton doesnt work, the function wont let me choose a layer. I tried creating a new layer with points, which i did automatically with qgis (line intersections). Since there are parallel lines, there were parallel points, and so the calculating the shortes lenght between points didnt work.

Comment: Try the solution I linked above using Network tools. That should work.

Comment: I did try it before i posted the original question. Problem was, that adding points all over the network, at the endpoints (dangles) is difficult when doing so manually, because the network is quite large. Thats why I hat alle line intersection get a point, but as i pointed out, too many points where created, and they were also parallel. I'm probably have a lapse of thought becuase i cannot solve the problem

Comment: See also here how to get rid of side branches and find dangles: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/444603/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/427802/88814

Comment: I dont want to be rude, I really appreciate your effort in helping me. I read both links thoroughly , but Its not working. There are too many things I'm not understanding along the way, which is frustrating.

Comment: Yeah, so you should start working step by step and come back to tell us what you've tried and the very point you're stuck. Then we can solve this problem and you can continue with the next step(s) until you're stuck again. That's how this site works, see [tour]. If you just tell us "it didn't work", how could we know where to start helping? So start creating a point layer with dangles from the railway lines first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149366/discussion-between-rtaani-and-babel).